# ASP.net Adding to Gridview using C# and saving to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This may be a silly question but I can not figure it out as I have never used ASP.net before, What I want to do is have the user add a type of sales order to a grid view by selecting the product qty and then inputting that to a grid view so they can make a type of list. What I have so far is it adds a one row to the list and then when i try to add another it replaces the first one instead of adding to the previous one.

Next when they have finished the list I want to save it to the data base it is a salesOrder SalesORderLine Relationship in Access. Below is my code for all three the ASP.net c# code and the two matching Classes SalesOrder and SalesOrder Line

Asp.net c# Code

```
namespace ChocoMamboAsp
{
    public partial class  SalesOrderForm : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        SalesOrder _order = null;


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SalesOrderID"] == null)
            {
                    _order = new SalesOrder();
                    populateCustomerCombo();
                    populateEmployeeCombo();
                    populateProductCombo();
                    dgvOrderLine.DataSource = _order.getOrderLinesTable();

            }
            else
            {
                _order = new SalesOrder(long.Parse(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SalesOrderID"].ToString()));

                    populateCustomerCombo();
                    populateEmployeeCombo();
                    populateProductCombo();

                    displayRecord();


                //string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + _strTableName;
                //_dst = new DataSet();
                //_dbConn.fillDataSet(_dst, strSQL, _strTableName);
                //dgvOrderLine.DataSource = _dst.Tables[_strTableName];
                //dgvOrderLine.DataBind();

            }

        }


        #region Mutators
        /// <summary>
        /// Pre-Condtion:   Event Call
        /// Post-Condition: calculates the item total
        /// Description:    Calculates the line total for each item in the grid list
        /// </summary>
        private void calculateLineTotal()
        {
            //int intQty = 0;
            //decimal decPrice = 0.0M;
            var total = 0;
            foreach (GridViewRow row in dgvOrderLine.Rows)
            {
                var numberLabel = row.FindControl("LineTotal") as Label;
                int number;
                if (int.TryParse(numberLabel.Text, out number))
                {
                    total += number;

                }
            }
            txtSubTotal.Text = total.ToString();
            try
            {
                //DataRowView drvCost = (DataRowView)cboProducts.SelectedItem;
                //txtPrice.Text = decimal.Parse(drvCost["ProductsCost"].ToString()).ToString("c2");
                //intQty = int.Parse(txtQty.Text);
                //decPrice = decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text.Substring(txtPrice.Text.IndexOf('$') + 1));
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                //this exception will occur if txtPrice, txtQuantity, and cboProduct is
                //empty, and which we can safely ignore.
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                //this exception will occur if cboProduct is empty, which we can safely ignore
            }

            //decimal decLineTotal = decPrice * intQty;
            //txtSubTotal.Text = decLineTotal.ToString("c2");
            //calculateGrandTotal();
        }


        private void calculateGrandTotal()
        {
            try
            {
                decimal decGrandTotal = decimal.Parse(_order.getOrderLinesTable().Compute
                                                      ("Sum(LineTotal)", "").ToString());
                lblTotal.Text = decGrandTotal.ToString("c2");
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                //this exception will occur if tblOrderLine is empty which we can safely ignore
            }
        }


        #endregion

        protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                assignChildData();
                _order.OrderLineClass.addNewRecord();
                dgvOrderLine.DataSource = _order.getOrderLinesTable();
                dgvOrderLine.DataBind();
                calculateGrandTotal();
                emptyControls();



        }


        #region Accessors

        private void displayRecord()
        {
            cboRetailer.SelectedValue = _order.RetailerID.ToString();
            dtpSalesOrder.Text = _order.SalesDate.ToString();
            cboSalesAgent.SelectedValue = _order.EmployeeID.ToString();
            txtRetailerAddress.Text = _order.RetailerAddress;
            txtRetailerPhone.Text = _order.RetailerPhone;
            lblTotal.Text = _order.SaleTotal.ToString("c2");
            dgvOrderLine.DataSource = _order.getOrderLinesTable();
            dgvOrderLine.DataBind();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_order.getOrderLinesTable());
        }

        private void populateCustomerCombo()
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                cboRetailer.DataSource = _order.getCustomers();
                cboRetailer.DataValueField = "RetailerID";
                cboRetailer.DataTextField = "RetailerName";
                cboRetailer.DataBind();
            }

            //cboRetailer.DataSource = _order.getCustomers();
            //cboRetailer.DisplayMember = "RetailerName";
            //cboRetailer.ValueMember = "RetailerID";
            //cboRetailer.SelectedIndex = -1; //will make the combo box select nothing
        }

        private void populateEmployeeCombo()
        {
            cboSalesAgent.DataSource = _order.getEmployee();
            cboSalesAgent.DataValueField = "EmployesID";
            cboSalesAgent.DataTextField = "EmployeeFirstName";
            cboSalesAgent.DataBind(); 

            //cboSalesAgent.DataSource = _order.getEmployee();
            //cboSalesAgent.DisplayMember = "EmployeeFirstName";
            //cboSalesAgent.ValueMember = "EmployesID";
            //cboSalesAgent.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }

        private void populateProductCombo()
        {
            //cboProducts.DataSource = _order.getProducts();
            //cboProducts.DataValueField = "ProductsID";
            //cboProducts.DataTextField = "ProdustsName";
            //cboProducts.DataBind(); 

                cboProducts.DataSource = _order.getProducts();
                cboProducts.DataTextField = "ProdustsName";
                cboProducts.DataValueField = "ProductsID";
                cboProducts.DataBind();



        }

        private void displayGridRecord()
        {
             //assign the values to the variables to be used for calculations

           //int grdid = int.Parse(dgvOrderLine.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text.ToString());

           //decimal decPrice = decimal.Parse(dgvOrderLine["Price",
           //                                  dgvOrderLine.Rows[2].Cells.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
           //int intQty = int.Parse(dgvOrderLine["Qty",
           //                       dgvOrderLine.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

           //cboProducts.SelectedValue = long.Parse(dgvOrderLine["ProductsID",
           //                                 dgvOrderLine.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
           //txtPrice.Text = decPrice.ToString("c2");
           //txtQty.Text = intQty.ToString();
           //decimal decLineTotal = decPrice * intQty;
           //txtSubTotal.Text = decLineTotal.ToString("c2");
           //_order.OrderLineClass.PKID = long.Parse(dgvOrderLine["SaleOrderLineID",
           //                                 dgvOrderLine.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        }

        private void emptyTopControls()
        {
            cboSalesAgent.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cboRetailer.SelectedIndex = -1;
            txtRetailerAddress.Text = "";
            txtRetailerPhone.Text = "";
        }


        private void emptyControls()
        {
            cboProducts.SelectedIndex = -1;
            txtPrice.Text = "";
            txtQty.Text = "";
            txtSubTotal.Text = string.Empty;
            btnInsert.Enabled = true;
            btnUpdate.Enabled = false;
            dgvOrderLine.DataSource = _order.getOrderLinesTable();
        }

        private void assignChildData()
        {
            _order.OrderLineClass.ProductsID = long.Parse(cboProducts.SelectedValue.ToString());
            _order.OrderLineClass.Qty = long.Parse(txtQty.Text);
            _order.OrderLineClass.Price = decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text.Substring
                                                          (txtPrice.Text.IndexOf('$') +     1));
            _order.OrderLineClass.SalesOrderID = _order.PKID;
            _order.OrderLineClass.LineTotal = decimal.Parse(txtSubTotal.Text);
            _order.OrderLineClass.ProdustsName = cboProducts.Text;
        }



        private void assignData()
        {
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpSalesOrder.Text);
            _order.RetailerID = long.Parse(cboRetailer.SelectedValue.ToString());
            _order.SalesDate =  date;
            _order.EmployeeID = long.Parse(cboSalesAgent.SelectedValue.ToString());
            _order.RetailerAddress = txtRetailerAddress.Text;
            _order.RetailerPhone = txtRetailerPhone.Text;
            _order.SaleTotal = decimal.Parse(lblTotal.Text.Substring
                                              (lblTotal.Text.IndexOf('$') + 1));
        }
        #endregion

        protected void cboRetailer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dt = _order.getCustomers();
            var changed = cboRetailer.SelectedItem;
            if (changed != cboRetailer.SelectedItem)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (dt.Rows[i]["RetailerID"].ToString() == cboRetailer.SelectedValue)
                    {
                        txtRetailerAddress.Text = dt.Rows[i]["RetailerAddress"].ToString();
                        txtRetailerPhone.Text = dt.Rows[i]["RetailerPhone"].ToString();

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void cboRetailer_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dt = _order.getCustomers();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dt.Rows[i]["RetailerID"].ToString() == cboRetailer.SelectedValue)
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('test')</script>");
                    txtRetailerAddress.Text = dt.Rows[i]["RetailerAddress"].ToString();
                    txtRetailerPhone.Text = dt.Rows[i]["RetailerPhone"].ToString();

                }
            }
        }

        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = true;
        }

        protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dtpSalesOrder.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            Calendar1.Visible = false;
        }

        protected void cboProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dt = _order.getProducts();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dt.Rows[i]["ProductsID"].ToString() == cboProducts.SelectedValue)
                {
                    txtPrice.Text = dt.Rows[i]["ProductsCost"].ToString();


                }
            }
        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            assignData();
            _order.saveData();
            _order.OrderLineClass.saveData();
            Response.Redirect("SalesOrderGird.aspx");
        }


    }
}

Sales Order Class

namespace ChocoMamboAsp
{
    class SalesOrder
    {
         #region Instance Variables
        //list of variables
        /// <summary>
        /// The variables are to set up both the Connection and the table names 
        /// in order to get the correct information from the data base
        /// The Dataset is to store all the infromation from the database table
        /// The dbConnection is the database name we use to connect to the database.
        /// </summary>
        long _lngPKID = 0;
        string _strTableName = "SalesOrder";
        dbConnection _dbConn = new dbConnection("|DataDirectory|ChocoMambo.accdb");
        DataSet _dst = new DataSet();
        DataRow _drwRecord = null;
        // create an instance of the OrderLine class so we can create the relationship between the tables tblOrders and tblOrderLines
        SalesOrderLine _orderLine = null;    

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for new Order
        /// </summary>
        public SalesOrder()
        {
            loadDataSet();
            addNewRecord();
            _orderLine = new SalesOrderLine(_dst, _lngPKID);
            createRelationship();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for existing Order
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pLongID">The record ID of the order that will be used in this class</param>
        public SalesOrder(long pLongID)
        {
            _lngPKID = pLongID;
            loadDataSet();
            _orderLine = new SalesOrderLine(_dst, _lngPKID);
            createRelationship();
            assignFields();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public long EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public DateTime SalesDate { get; set; }
        public string RetailerAddress { get; set; }
        public long RetailerID { get; set; } //this is the retailer anything with CustomerNumber is now Retailer
        public decimal SaleTotal { get; set; }
        public string RetailerPhone { get; set; }


        public long PKID
        {
            get { return _lngPKID; }
        }

        >
        public SalesOrderLine OrderLineClass
        {
            get
            {
                return _orderLine;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Accessors


        private void loadDataSet()
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + _strTableName;

            if (_lngPKID > 0)
                strSQL += " WHERE SalesOrderID = " + _lngPKID;

            _dbConn.fillDataSet(_dst, strSQL, _strTableName);
        }


        private void createRelationship()
        {
            if (_dst.Relations.Contains("orderRelationship") == false)
            {
                _dst.Relations.Add("orderRelationship", _dst.Tables["SalesOrder"].Columns["SalesOrderID"],
                                                       _dst.Tables["SalesOrderLine"].Columns["SalesOrderID"]);
            }
        }


        private void assignFields()
        {
            EmployeeID = long.Parse(_dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows[0]["EmployesID"].ToString());
            SalesDate = DateTime.Parse(_dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows[0]["SalesDate"].ToString());
            RetailerAddress = _dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows[0]["RetailerAddress"].ToString();
            RetailerID = long.Parse(_dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows[0]["RetailerID"].ToString());
            SaleTotal = decimal.Parse(_dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows[0]["SaleTotal"].ToString());
            RetailerPhone = _dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows[0]["RetailerPhone"].ToString();
        }


        public DataTable getCustomers()
        {
            return _dbConn.GetDataTable("Retailer");
        }
        public DataTable getEmployee()
        {
            return _dbConn.GetDataTable("Employes");
        }

        public DataTable getProducts()
        {
            return _dbConn.GetDataTable("Products");
        }


        public DataTable getOrderLinesTable()
        {
            return _dst.Tables["SalesOrderLine"];
        }



        #endregion

        #region Mutators


        public void saveData()
        {
            if (_lngPKID <= 0)
                addNewRecord();
            else
                updateRecord();

            _dbConn.SaveData(_dst, _strTableName);
        }


        private void addNewRecord()
        {
            _drwRecord = _dst.Tables[_strTableName].NewRow();
            _drwRecord.BeginEdit();
            _drwRecord["SalesDate"] = SalesDate;
            _drwRecord["RetailerAddress"] = RetailerAddress;
            _drwRecord["RetailerPhone"] = RetailerPhone;
            _drwRecord["RetailerID"] = RetailerID;
            _drwRecord["SaleTotal"] = SaleTotal;
            _drwRecord["EmployesID"] = EmployeeID;
            _drwRecord.EndEdit();
            _dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows.Add(_drwRecord);
            _lngPKID = long.Parse(_drwRecord["SalesOrderID"].ToString());
        }


        private void updateRecord()
        {
            _drwRecord = _dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows.Find(_lngPKID);
            _drwRecord.BeginEdit();
            _drwRecord["SalesDate"] = SalesDate;
            _drwRecord["RetailerAddress"] = RetailerAddress;
            _drwRecord["RetailerPhone"] = RetailerPhone;
            _drwRecord["RetailerID"] = RetailerID;
            _drwRecord["SaleTotal"] = SaleTotal;
            _drwRecord["EmployesID"] = EmployeeID;
            _drwRecord.EndEdit();       

        }

        #endregion
    }
}


SalesOrdeLine Class


namespace ChocoMamboAsp
{
    class SalesOrderLine
    {
        #region Instance Variables

        long _lngFKID = 0, _lngPKID = 0;
        string _strTableName = "SalesOrderLine";
        dbConnection _dbConn = new dbConnection("|DataDirectory|ChocoMambo.accdb");
        DataSet _dst;
        DataRow _drwRecord = null;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors


        public SalesOrderLine(DataSet pDataSet, long pLongID)
        {
            _dst = pDataSet;
            _lngFKID = pLongID;
            loadDataSet();
            assignFields();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public long ProductsID { get; set; }
        public decimal Price{ get; set; }
        public long Qty { get; set; }
        public long SalesOrderID { get; set; }
        public decimal LineTotal { get; set; }
        public string ProdustsName { get; set; }


        public long PKID
        {
            get { return _lngPKID; }
            set { _lngPKID = value; }
        }

        #endregion

        public DataTable getOrderLinesTable()
        {
            return _dst.Tables["SalesOrderLine"];
        }

        #region Accessors


        public void loadDataSet()
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qrySalesOrderLine";//maybe here
            strSQL += " WHERE SalesOrderID = " + _lngFKID; //here

            _dbConn.fillDataSet(_dst, strSQL, _strTableName);
        }


        private void assignFields()
        {
            try
            {
                ProductsID = long.Parse(_dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows[0]["ProductsID"].ToString());
                Price = decimal.Parse(_dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows[0]["Price"].ToString());
                Qty = long.Parse(_dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows[0]["Qty"].ToString());
                SalesOrderID = long.Parse(_dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows[0]["SalesOrderID"].ToString());
                LineTotal = decimal.Parse(_dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows[0]["LineTotal"].ToString());
                ProdustsName = _dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows[0]["ProdustsName"].ToString();
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                //this exception occurs when order line row is empty which we can safely ignore.
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Mutators


        public void saveData()
        {
            _dbConn.SaveData(_dst, _strTableName);
        }


        public void addNewRecord()
        {
            _drwRecord = _dst.Tables[_strTableName].NewRow();
            _drwRecord.BeginEdit();
            _drwRecord["ProductsID"] = ProductsID;
            _drwRecord["Price"] = Price;
            _drwRecord["Qty"] = Qty;
            _drwRecord["SalesOrderID"] = SalesOrderID;
            _drwRecord["LineTotal"] = LineTotal;
            _drwRecord["ProdustsName"] = ProdustsName;
            _drwRecord.EndEdit();
            _dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows.Add(_drwRecord);
            _lngPKID = long.Parse(_drwRecord["SaleOrderLineID"].ToString());
        }

        public void updateRecord()
        {
            try
            {
                _drwRecord = _dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows.Find(_lngPKID);
                _drwRecord.BeginEdit();
                _drwRecord["ProductsID"] = ProductsID;
                _drwRecord["Price"] = Price;
                _drwRecord["Qty"] = Qty;
                _drwRecord["SalesOrderID"] = SalesOrderID;
                _drwRecord["LineTotal"] = LineTotal;
                _drwRecord["ProdustsName"] = ProdustsName;
                _drwRecord.EndEdit();
            }
            catch (System.NullReferenceException)
            { }
        }


        public void deleteOrderLine(long pLongPKID)
        {
            _dst.Tables[_strTableName].Rows.Find(pLongPKID).Delete();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I do not know how to do any of this.

Thank you Again

Comment: That's an awful lot of code. Can you narrow it down?

Comment: Sorry for the amount of code,
OK so in basic terms what I want to do is on the button click method I want to add a new row to the gridview which is what I thought _order.OrderLineClass.addnewRow() did in the sales order this then 
This created a new row in the data table and then I would get the rows back and binding the datasource of the grideview with dgvOrderLine.DataSource = _order.getOrderLinesTable();
and then binding the source with dgvvOrderLine.DataBinding(); hope this helps Thanks again